# How to use "fallback" method for PHP curl (HTTPS)?

Tags: php, curl, monitoring, ping, fsockopen

**Situation**: I'm improving some code on a PHP based monitoring web app that checks the health of other web apps/services.

**Goal**:  we are using CURL as a primary method to get headers to ensure the monitored app is accessible via HTTP return codes.  **This works great as of now**.  However, we are trying to build in a "fallback" method in which IF the CURL HTTP code response from the monitored app is outside of our defined variables (ie http code 404), PHP would then use a PING-like function to check if there is *any* response at that same address (for example, webserver is still "running" (occupying the given port) but not serving proper headers).

**Problem**:  Our fallback method (stream_socket_client) DOES work for non-secure sites as we can simply define "hostname:port" which BOTH curl and stream_socket_client can use.  However, If we want to monitor a secure site (HTTPS), curl requires the HTTPS protocol to be defined before the host - which will then make our fallback method (stream_socket_client) function fail as it only uses host:port format.

So, for example:

$URL:  https://example.com:443 (this would turn a "GOOD" CURL response, but a down stream_socket_client response)

$URL:  example.com:443 (this would return a "UP" stream_socket_client response, but a "DOWN" CURL response)

So, if we used https://example.com:443 as our URL, and the webserver became unresponsive, but is still running on that port, both would fail because HTTPs is defined.

This is a simplified version of our current code:

```
<?php

    $url = "example.com:80";

    function curl($url) {



        $handle = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        $response = curl_exec($handle);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


        if($httpCode >= 200 && $httpCode < 400 || $httpCode == 401 || $httpCode == 405) {

                echo "CURL GOOD, $httpCode";
                echo "STATUS: GREEN";
            } 

            else {

                $fp = stream_socket_client("$url", $errno, $errstr);

                if (!$fp) {
                    echo "CURL BAD, PING DOWN";
                    echo "STATUS: RED";
                } 

                else {
                    echo "CURL BAD PING UP";
                    echo "STATUS: YELLOW";
                }
            }

        curl_close($handle);

    };
?>
```

Any ideas how to use a fallback method to check if a port is open or not? I don't have to stick with PHP, can use some JS, but would prefer PHP.

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks to  @drew010 I know I need to ultimately use fsockopen. However, I'll need to use parse_url() which can then pass a "sterile" URL to fsockopen for fallback "ping" check.

However, I'm not sure how to strip ONLY the protocol and leave the port and sub path (if defined). I'm also not sure how to pass the sterile URL to the fsockeopn function to use for the check.  So far I have the code below, but I know I'm missing some code.

The below code parses `http://example.com` to `example.com`.

```
function parseurl($url) {
    $url = 'http://example.com:80';
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

    //this works for stripping protocol and "wwww" but need to leave port and sub path if defined.

    if (!$host)
        $host = $url;

    if (substr($host, 0, 4) == "www.")
        $host = substr($host, 4);
    if (strlen($host) > 50)
        $host = substr($host, 0, 47) . '...';
    return $host;
}


  // How to pass steril URL to PING function??

function ping($host, $timeout = 1) {

    if (!fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout)) {
        return false;
        echo "OPEN";
    }

    else {
        echo "CLOSED";
    }
 }
```

Comment: ping wont tell you if a web server is running

Comment: @rtfm  depends on how you define "running"  It will tell you if it's listening on that port.

Comment: i said "web server"

Comment: not sure what you mean, but the fallback method only needs to report if anything is occupying that port.  The primary CURL method is to check if the web server is actually functional.

Comment: there are a lot of machines that will respond to a ping request that are not web-servers. you said you want to check the health of a "webapp" a machine responding to a ping does not mean the webserver is working and if its not then their is no webapp. we use multiple  external services to monitor our servers, none of them use ping, its pointless, we dont want to know if the server is responding to ping, we are not in the ping reponce business.

Comment: Uhh, yeah, that's why we are using CURL as our primary method.  No need to argue here man.  In our case, we need to know if something is occupying that port IF the webapp/webserver is unresponsive. There are many web servers out there that can run while not serving HTTP headers.   Thanks tho.

Comment: if fsockopen() can connect then the port is "occupied".

Comment: @drew010 yes, I know this.  But how do I use fsocketopen with HTTPs?

Comment: If you're simply checking if there's something listening on the port, then you shouldn't care if you need to use TLS/SSL or any other protocol right?  I thought the use case is: curl issues https request, gets back an HTTP status code that's not in your list (or fails), so then you fsockopen the port and if it connects, it's "curl bad ping up", otherwise "curl bad ping down"

Comment: @drew010 right, we don't care.  The problem is that the address supplied for PHP to use for CURL and the "fallback" option has to be the exact same address which is supplied via config file.  So, there are some services that we monitor that ONLY listen on TLS. Therefore, in order for CURL to work, we have to specify the HTTPS protocol, which isn't compatible with fsockopen,

Comment: I think I have a better understanding of what the problem is.  I think you should check out [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) to see how you can break down something like `https://example.com/` into the hostname and port so you can pass it to fsockopen.

Comment: @drew010 after much research, you're right Sir. Thanks so much, got me on the right path I think.  I'm in a bit over my head now...but I do know what needs to happen.  I did update my question.  Thanks so much. If you have any more insight, would love to hear it. \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

This script uses CURL to check if given HOST is serving a webpage. 
If NOT, use a PING function to check if anything is listening on given port.

```
<?php

     * This script uses CURL to check if given HOST is serving a webpage. 
     * If NOT, use a PING function to check if anything is listening on given port.
    //* URL MUST contain a PORT after HOST
    //* URL CAN include any protocol or sub-path


    // sanitizes URL to host:port:path ONLY. (if PORT, PATH don't exist, it is ignored):

    function url_to_domain($url) {

        $url = 'http://google.com:80';

        echo "Input URL ..... $url<br />\n";

        $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $port = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT);
        $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

        // If the URL can't be parsed, use the original URL
        // Change to "return false" if you don't want that

        if (!$host)
            echo "fail";
            // $host = $url;

            // remove "http/s" and "www" :

        if (substr($host, 0, 4) == "www.")
            $host = substr($host, 4);
        if (strlen($host) > 50)
            $host = substr($host, 0, 47) . '...';

        // contruct sanitized URL, add ":port/path" to HOST:

        return $host . ":" . $port . $path;

 }


     // pings "sanitized" URL:

    $url = (url_to_domain($url));

    $fp = pfsockopen($url, $errno, $errstr, $timeout = 5);
    if (!$fp) {

        echo "Ping URL ...... $url <br />\n ";
        echo "URL status ..... CLOSED <br />\n";
        echo "Error ............... $errstr ($errno)<br />\n";

     } 

    else {
        // $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        // $out .= "$url\r\n";
        // $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        //fwrite ($fp, $out);
        //displays header: 
           /*    
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                echo fgets($fp, 128);
             } 
        */
        // fclose($fp);

       echo "Ping URL ...... $url <br />\n  ";
        echo "URL status .... OPEN";

    }


 ?>
```